# IBM MFP 7.1: Will applications still work after applying fixpacks?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have a MFP 7.1 server with one runtime currently deployed for use.

Will the application binaries already installed on phones still work after applying the fixpacks?

Or do i have to plan to upgrade the runtime and deploy a new application binary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix pack you apply will typically be to the MobileFirst Studio or the Server runtime. If you've applied it to MobileFirst Studio & rebuilt your app, then this must be redistributed to the end users to gain advantage of any fixes that are part of this fix pack.

Comment: So existing apps will still continue to be able to connect to the MFP server (with fix pack applied) and work?

Comment: Yes. Existing apps will continue to work - only they will not receive the benefit of fixes included in the fixpack